# PHP readfile content corruption on Azure Web App(Linux)

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am having an error on a when delivering files from an azure Web Apps.

This is a Azure App Service on Linux running `PHP 8.0.17 (cli) (built: Mar 25 2022 18:59:25) ( NTS )`

Downloaded documents get corrupted and modified (though the content size stays the same).

Running several tests, I came up with this code to reproduce the issue:

This breaks the PDF file see diff bellow:
`pdf1.php`

```php
<?php
$file = '/home/site/wwwroot/storage/temp/IFU.pdf';
readfile($file);
```

This seems to deliver the file properly:
`pdf2.php`

```php
<?php

$file = '/home/site/wwwroot/storage/temp/IFU.pdf';

$fp = fopen($file, 'rb');

while (!feof($fp)) {
    print(fread($fp, 2048));
}
fclose($fp);
```

You can see here the first bytes are cut off

[image]

and added here:
[image]

Any ideas?

Related/Similar topics:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/953763/php-stream-copy-to-stream-to-php-output-corrupts-d.html
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/42685

Comment: Could please help us here which version of symfony you are using? As suggested here in this git hub issue https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/42681 can you try downgrading symfony version to "6.0.9"

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MSFT As you can see,  I am not using any Symfony or Laravel here. Pure PHP.

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MSFT

Here is a repo to reproduce the issue: 
https://github.com/klodoma/azure-linux-php8

Just deploy it a on default azure linux app and you have the problem. 

See: 
https://www-php8-test.azurewebsites.net/tt1.php
https://www-php8-test.azurewebsites.net/tt4.php

Answer (score 0):

Our product team has investigated this issue and Based on your requirement/setup, you may try the following workarounds:

- Potential work-around is Set a custom docker image:

```html
az webapp config container set --name "your-site-name" --resource-group "your-resource-group" --docker-custom-image-name "mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/php:8.0-apache_20220805.1.tuxprod"
```

**Note**: this image takes about 6 to 7 minutes to pull.

**Warning**: If you use the above work-around, you must remove the work-around after App Service has upgraded to version 99.0.0.0 or higher.

From the Kudu (SCM) site, Select "Environment", and look for the PLATFORM_VERSION environment variable.The major version (first number in the 4-number version string) e.g. "99.0.7.577" if you see the major version as 99 or 100 you should remove the custom container config, make sure to set the App Setting **WEBSITES_DISABLE_FPM=true**, and change back to specifying PHP 8.x as the stack

[image]

The following three commands are the instructions to remove the above workaround:

```html
     az webapp config container delete --name <app-name> --resource-group<resource-group-name>     
     az webapp config appsettings set --name <app-name> --resource-group <group-name> --settings WEBSITES_DISABLE_FPM="true"    
     az webapp config set --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <app-name> --linux-fx-version "PHP|8.0"
```

Comment: I can confirm that this "workaround" is NOT WORKING. 
These 2 requests should have the same response content:
https://www-php8-test.azurewebsites.net/tt4.php
https://www-php8-test.azurewebsites.net/tt1.php

Comment: @klodoma I can see both the responses are same and validated with [online file difference tool](https://codebeautify.org/file-diff) even it says No changes were found

Comment: Yes, I played around with it, re-created the service and now it seems to work with the fix you provided. A major difference is that the webserver is apache and not nginx anymore. 

I get a feeling, that this issue is happening only with NGINX? (WEBSITES_DISABLE_FPM seems to play a role). I'll dig in a bit more.

Comment: I'll post more comments here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/953763/php-stream-copy-to-stream-to-php-output-corrupts-d.html - as it seems more suited that stackoverflow for discussions.